# HTML wont show buttons in same row

Tags: html

I am currently in the process of trying to create three buttons in the same line, however the buttons wont work on the same line, could you please advise or help.

I am getting an error, I know that the html is wrong as I have three openings and only 1 closing  tag

```html
echo "<td><input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=/"products home/" onclick=\"window.location.href='Electronic and Entertainment Products.php'\">;
echo "<td><input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=/"Entertainment Products/" onclick=\"window.location.href='Entertainment Products.php'\">;
echo "<td><input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=/"Electronic/" onclick=\"window.location.href='Electronic.php'\"></td>";
```

.

Could you please advise or re-write the code for me.

```html
echo "<td><input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=/"products home/" onclick=\"window.location.href='Electronic and Entertainment Products.php'\"></td>";
echo "<td><input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=/"Entertainment Products/" onclick=\"window.location.href='Entertainment Products.php'\"></td>";
echo "<td><input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=/"Electronic/" onclick=\"window.location.href='Electronic.php'\"></td>";
```

Comment: You have three opening `<td>` tags but only one closing tag `</td>`

Comment: The `value` quotes are also incorrectly/not escaped. You should just use single quote strings. That way you do not have to worry about escaping.

Comment: could you please tell me how to change the openings and closings.

Comment: @james_91 Add `</td>` to the end of the two first cells.

Comment: close the tags on each echo like you have in the last one

Comment: I have however still getting an error, echo "<td><input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=/"products home/" onclick=\"window.location.href='Electronic and Entertainment Products.php'\"></td>";
echo "<td><input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=/"Entertainment Products/" onclick=\"window.location.href='Entertainment Products.php'\"></td>";
echo "<td><input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=/"Electronic/" onclick=\"window.location.href='Electronic.php'\"></td>";

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn — That doesn't matter. End tags for table data cell elements are optional in HTML.

Comment: @james_91 — Edit your question to include the HTML (not the PHP) needed to reproduce your problem. Your existing code puts all the buttons on the same line.

Comment: I now getting an which says unexpected 'products' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Use `echo "<td><input class=button_normal type=button value=products home onclick=window.location.href='Electronic and Entertainment Products.php'></td>";
    echo "<td><input class=button_normal type=button value=Entertainment Products onclick=window.location.href='Entertainment Products.php'></td>";
    echo "<td><input class=button_normal type=button value=Electronic onclick=window.location.href='Electronic.php'></td>";`

Comment: Ketan, I want it all in the same row please not in new columns,.

Comment: @Quentin You are right. Never came across that little tidbit before

Comment: @james_91 — You want them in the same row and not in new columns? So you want them in the same cell then? (Why are you using buttons with JavaScript to make them act like links anyway, just use links)

Comment: I want them in the same row please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even though you are missing `<table>` and `<tr>` tags it still should be displayed in a single line.

It's possible that parent container has some style defined that causes your code to be split into separate lines.

I assume those `<td>s` are inside one `<tr>` and you have your styles/properties defined. Even if you don't it's still gonna work as intended showing all three buttons in same line.

https://jsfiddle.net/xLgxsme7/3/

As you can see those elements are in line so.
So I'd say you have some style maybe copied or something.

If you want to have them one row you could always remove `<td>` tags from inbetween and just leave it like this:

```
echo "<td><input class=button_normal type=button value=products home onclick=window.location.href='Electronic and Entertainment Products.php'>"; 
echo "<input class=button_normal type=button value=Entertainment Products onclick=window.location.href='Entertainment Products.php'>"; 
echo "<input class=button_normal type=button value=Electronic onclick=window.location.href='Electronic.php'></td>";
```

so it's all in just one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing `<tr>` and `<table>` from your code?

```
echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<td><input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=/"products home/" onclick=\"window.location.href='Electronic and Entertainment Products.php'\"></td>";
echo "<td><input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=/"Entertainment Products/" onclick=\"window.location.href='Entertainment Products.php'\"></td>";
echo "<td><input class=\"button_normal\" type=\"button\" value=/"Electronic/" onclick=\"window.location.href='Electronic.php'\"></td>";
echo "</tr></table>";
```